# Wordpress Search showing a blank page for empty results

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I've had to put together a custom search that sends the user to different search result pages based on which form they've filled out and the search also has been set to search custom post types.

When the search finds a result everything displays correctly but when it does an empty search it doesn't seem to be running the content-none.php template. Instead of "Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords." It's just an empty page with the header and footer.

For an example you can go to: http://biozymeconnect.ev-labs.com/reseller/ and in the second input use "tx" for a search with results and then something random for a search without results.

Details:

- Base Theme: underscores
- Framework: Foundation by Zurb

Custom Post Type search changes were made using this code http://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/

```
/**
 * Extend WordPress search to include custom fields
 *
 * http://adambalee.com
 */

/**
 * Join posts and postmeta tables
 *
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join
 */
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {    
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );

/**
 * Modify the search query with posts_where
 *
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where
 */
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );

/**
 * Prevent duplicates
 *
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_distinct
 */
function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

To customize the search results I used this tutorial http://wpgarage.com/code-snippets/how-to-customize-multiple-search-result-pages-in-wordpress/

edited the search.php to be

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Search Results */
$search_refer = $_GET["site_section"];
if ($search_refer == 'reseller') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/reseller-search.php'); }
elseif ($search_refer == 'site-search') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/dealer-search.php'); }; ?>
```

I edited the reseller-search.php and dealer-search.php to be.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * @package Biozyme_Connect
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'bzconnect' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
            <span style="background-color:#f87d20; display:block; padding:4px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase;">*Please note that you will be required to login after clicking the link to receive your discounted rates.</span>
            <table width="100%" class="search-results">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Order</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                        /* Start the Loop */
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                            /**
                             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                             */
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search-reseller' );

                        endwhile;
                        echo '</tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';

                        the_posts_navigation();

                    else :

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

                    endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

content-none.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying a message that posts cannot be found.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Biozyme_Connect
 */

?>

<section class="no-results not-found">
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Nothing Found', 'bzconnect' ); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .page-header -->

    <div class="page-content">
        <?php
        if ( is_home() && current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) : ?>

            <p><?php printf( wp_kses( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%1$s">Get started here</a>.', 'bzconnect' ), array( 'a' => array( 'href' => array() ) ) ), esc_url( admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ) ); ?></p>

        <?php elseif ( is_search() ) : ?>

            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'bzconnect' ); ?></p>
            <?php
                get_search_form();

        else : ?>

            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'It seems we can&rsquo;t find what you&rsquo;re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.', 'bzconnect' ); ?></p>
            <?php
                get_search_form();

        endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .page-content -->
</section><!-- .no-results -->
```

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); did you try with debug on?

Comment: Thanks I haven't used that before. I can see where it's throwing an error where I've added conditional statements for a page or children of a page.

`<?php elseif ($post->post_parent == 136) : ?>
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
 'theme_location' => 'primary', 
 'container' => '', 
 'menu_class' => '', 
 'menu_id' => '', 
 'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
 'depth' => 2
 ) ); ?>`
and 

`<?php elseif ($post->post_parent == 136) : ?>
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
 'theme_location' => 'primary', 
 'container' => '', 
 'menu_class' => '', 
 'menu_id' => '', 
 'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
 'depth' => 2
 ) ); ?>`

Comment: I ended that with a basic 
`<?php else : ?> <?php echo ''; ?> <?php endif; ?>`
So I assumed it would default to that.

Comment: Ok this [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115390/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-when-using-post-post-parent[/link] pointed me in the right direction to remove the object errors I was getting but it's still just showing a white page.

Comment: Also add code from your `template-parts/content-none.php` file

Comment: I've added that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the link that your shared for search and checking 'view-source' it seems that the `content-none` template is not being loaded at all, as even the HTML doesn't show inside the `div.main`.

I can think of two reasons right now which might be causing this problem:

1.Check to ensure that you really do go into the `else:` condition. Although this is unlikely but it is good to be sure. So check it by doing something like

```
     else :
                echo 'Nothing found!';
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

            endif; ?>
```

Check if you can see `Nothing found!` on the page.

2. Make sure that the content-none.php file actually exists  i.e

   a. It is in the correct directory e.g `template-parts/content-none.php`, just make sure we are in the right path

   b. Filename is correct e.g it is not `cotent-none.php` or `content-noen.php` or something like this.

Comment: I can't believe what it was. The content-none.php template was there but when I looked closer I realized that it loaded with 0Kb of the file size so it wasn't reading anything. Thanks.